# Failed to install the requested application: The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined. - Flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I am facing an issue with launching my flutter app in the Xcode simulator. the android version of the app is working fine while testing with an android emulator, not getting any errors, even while successfully building the app, but I don't know what's going wrong with the Xcode. (IOS version)

flutter version: v2.5.3 | devtools: v2.8.0

**Error log:** (flutter run)

```
Unable to install /Users/USER_NAME/Documents/APP_NAME/main_files/source/wordpress_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on FEBE8117-5EC5-429F-820D-DA1F80359C7B. This is sometimes caused by a
malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install FEBE8117-5EC5-429F-820D-DA1F80359C7B
  /Users/USER_NAME/Documents/APP_NAME/main_files/source/wordpress_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My App Name</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(com.MY_NAME.MY_APP_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>myAppName</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The error suggests there is an issue with your `Info.plist` file. Can you share what your `Info.plist` file looks like?

Comment: sure, here is it: https://pastebin.com/pVhNRn8h

Comment: Don't try to hard code your CFBundleIdentifier, try using this `<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key><string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>`

Comment: Dear, Don't I have to replace CFBundleIdentifier value with my iOS package name?

Comment: `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` should be set to your iOS package name. Don't set the `CFBundleIdentifier` manually in your `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Man!!!! You are the god! It fixed my issue. WOW. Thanks a lot. Would you please post it as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer? It will help other people.

Comment: Sure, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is happening because your bundle identifier (`CFBundleIdentifier`) is not correct. `com.MY_NAME.MY_APP_NAME` is not an environment variable, and therefore cannot be evaluated using `$()`.

In flutter the `CFBundleIdentifier` should be set to the value of `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` which is an environment variable defined in `ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj`.

So, in your `Info.plist` file, replace:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(com.MY_NAME.MY_APP_NAME)</string>
```

With:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

This can sometimes be caused when you have not added your GoogleService-Info file

Comment: Nice catch! I had to try every solution I found until I found this easy fix

Answer (score 0):

The problem is In Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion. Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.

You need to paste the code in list file

CFBundleVersion
$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)

Comment: My CFBundleVersion looks like this:
https://imgur.com/ZD5YC8H

Comment: So, I replace CFBundleVersion value with $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)?